# How to add an ESP-IDF library to an external library

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, directory-structure, esp-idf, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to add an external library into my project.

My projectstructure looks like this:

```
-project
   -- main
     --- main.c
     --- displayfunctions.c (where i implement my Displayfunctions based on the library)
     --- 2 other .c files which got nothing to do with my Display
     --- CMakeLists.txt 
   -- components
     --- displaylibrary
       ---- CMAKELists.txt
       ---- all displayrelevant librarys pngle.c fontx.c etc..
       ---- include
          ----- all corresponding header files pngle.h fontx.h etc.
```

my `CMakeLists.txt` file in `project/components/displaylibrarys` looks like this:

```cmake
idf_component_register(
  SRCS
     "pngle.c"
     "decode_jpeg.c"
     "decode_png.c"
     "fontx.c"
     "ili9340.c"
  INCLUDE_DIRS
     "include")

include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)
```

when i try to compile my project I get the following Error Message:

```
../components/Displaylibrarys/fontx.c:7:10: fatal error: esp_spiffs.h: No such file or directory #include "esp_spiffs.h"
```

so apparantly my compiler does not link the in my external library included esp-idf library with an actual esp-idf library. I tried it with this approach too

```cmake
idf_component_register(
  SRCS
    "pngle.c"
    "decode_jpeg.c"
    "decode_png.c"
    "fontx.c"
    "ili9340.c"
  INCLUDE_DIRS
    "include"
  REQUIRES
    esp_spiffs)
```

but without a result. How should i properly tell my compiler that it knows this library?

Comment: The `REQUIRES` clause looks good except the component is called "spiffs" and not "esp_spiffs".

Comment: oh wow. That did the job... i was struggeling for 2 days. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Why did you repost the same question instead of following up on the original? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70186133/how-can-i-add-an-external-header-file-within-my-components-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ESP-IDF build system works with components. Your library is a component, and so are many parts of the ESP-IDF library.

As part of the component approach, your component needs to declare what other components it depends on. That's what the `REQUIRES` clause is for.

You almost got it right except the the component is called `spiffs` instead of `esp_spiffs`.

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "pngle.c" "decode_jpeg.c" "decode_png.c" "fontx.c" "ili9340.c"
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "include"
                       REQUIRES spiffs)
```

I usually check the ESP-IDF components directory to figure out the correct name. The component and directory name are the same: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components